# How to convert yuv V210 to h264 lossless with gst-launch-1.0 on Ubunut 18.04

Tags: gstreamer, vaapi, gst-launch-1.0

Is it possible to create an H264 video with profile Hi444PP  from YUV v210 encoded video using gst-launch?(
I'm trying to use vaapih264enc )

Comment: That depends on your hardware. Most likely the answer is "no".

Comment: I've a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz so I could use vaapih264enc via intel quick sync function, but I' don't know how to obtain a video encoded in h264 hi444pp

Comment: These implementations focus on consumer use cases. These are 420 to 99%. So no, you can't.